# How to run a script as if it's running at boot?

Tags: environment-variables, startup

I have a script running at boot time, however it's giving me errors I see in the log file. When I run it manually, it runs fine - probably the environment is changed.

Is there a way to run such a script in conditions it's running at boot without restarting?

Script is located in `/etc/init.d` with a symlink in `/etc/rc5.d/S97mounter.sh`.

Comment: What are the errors, how do you start the script at boot time ( via `/etc/init.d/` , `/etc/rc.local`, `crontab` entry `@reboot`)?

Comment: Might be looking for `su -`, which clears the environment unlike `su` or `sudo sh`. Of course, that won't solve the problem if it's related to the order in which services have started up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could run as root

`env - scriptname`

This will clear your environment before running the script, however, it will also keep your `shell`. To clear the environment and set the shell to `sh`, do the following:

`env -i /bin/sh -c scriptname`

This will then run the script using `/bin/sh`. However, this will not completely simulate the boot environment as this does not count for the other services that may not be running at the time.

I have found a similar question for simulating the crontab environment and there is a very useful solution posted by [mmccoo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2546509/3506015).

Using this you could run this in a script and reboot the host, then use the environment file to load your environment:

part of a boot script:

`env > /var/tmp/bootenv`

Then at normal runtime to set the same boot environment, do this:

```
env - `cat /var/tmp/bootenv` /bin/sh -c scriptname
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things that may be different when a program is started via a user session rather than a startup script:

- The program inherits many environment variables (including `PATH`, `HOME`, …).
- The program inherits several file descriptors, including a terminal.
- Limits may be different.

To run a program with a minimal environment and close the standard file descriptors, you can use something like

```
env -i PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin myprogram </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Check the `init` man page or other documentation on your system to see what environment variables it defines. Many programs intended to run as daemons will need `PATH` and nothing else. The `PATH` value above is the default for init on Debian.

Answer (score -1):

Without more information about what your script is doing and what errors you're getting, it's difficult to give an accurate answer. That being said, it's probably *possible* to recreate the environment, but it will likely be very difficult, requiring to unmount or bind-mount filesystems or other such fun things.

An alternative could be to create a virtual machine using something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org) and perform your debugging using that, allowing you to reboot the virtual machine as often as require without requiring you to reboot your host machine.